# finding expectation that involves the indicator function $1_A$ where A is the event $X<l, Y<m$ $X,Y$ are continuous RV. $l,m$ are numbers

Tags: expected-value, uniform-distribution

let $X,Y$ be independent random variables that follow a continuous uniform distribution with bounds $[a_1,b_1], [a_2,b_2]$ respectively, ${1}_A$ be the indicator function, $A$ be the event $X<l, Y < m$ where $m,l$ are real numbers, and $g(X)$ a function of the rv $X$. I was trying to find the expected value $E[g(X)1_A]$ but i was having trouble with it since the event A depends on 2 different random variables. I have been stuck on this for a while and would appreciate any help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: @Youem Yes, they are independent

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $$\mathbb E\left[g(X)\mathbf 1_A\right] = \mathbb E\left[g(X)\mathbf 1_{X\le m}\mathbf 1_{Y \le l}\right] = \mathbb E\left[g(X)\mathbf 1_{X\le m}\right]\mathbb E\left[\mathbf 1_{Y \le l}\right]$$

Can you finish?

---

Now If for example $X \sim \mathcal U\left([0, 3]\right)$, $Y \sim \mathcal U\left([1, 5]\right)$ and you want to compute $$\mathbb E\left[X^2 \mathbf 1_{X\le 2Y} \mathbf 1_{Y \le 2}\right] = \int_{1}^{2}\int_{0}^{\min \left\{2Y, 3\right\}} x^2\frac1{3-0}\mathrm dx\frac1{5-1}\mathrm d y = \int_{1}^{\frac32}\int_{0}^{2Y} x^2\frac13\mathrm dx\frac14\mathrm d y + \int_{\frac32}^{1}\int_{0}^{3} x^2\frac13\mathrm dx\frac14\mathrm d y + $$

Comment: Yes i can finish the rest, thank you sooo much. i have a quick follow up question if m instead depended on Y (so something like $X \leq Y+4$ instead of $X \leq m$ what would the answer look like

Comment: You should compute the double integral directly.

Comment: sorry i don't follow that. will you be kind enough to please give an example . I am kind of new to this. Thanks in advance :) .

Comment: I update the answer with an example.

Comment: Great thank you so much. So you just replace the upper bound with whichever of them is smaller. That min{2Y,3} would still be there in your final answer correct? and you would have to figure out some way to evaluate it (maybe replacing it with min(2E(Y),3} or something )

Comment: No you should divide your integral to two depending on which of them is the minimum.

Comment: Oh, so 2 cases, one case the min is 2Y and the other case, 3 is the min. So you get 2 different double integrals depending on which one is the min?

Comment: I added some details in the answer.

Comment: I am sorry, but i don't follow how the bounds changed :(. i searched online but nothing comes up ( a similar question shows up, but on closer inspection they aren't really that similar).

Comment: You divide your integral depending on the fact that minimum is $2y$ or $3$.

Comment: Ok, so if min is 2Y then the integral becomes $\int _1^2\:\int _0^{2Y}\:x^2\frac{1}{3}dx\frac{1}{4}dy$ but if min is 3 then integral becomes $\int _1^2\:\int _0^3\:x^2\frac{1}{3}dx\frac{1}{4}dy$ ?

Comment: No! You should change the bounds of $y$ accordingly.